# Mission Control acting very strangely with Finder and Google Chrome

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome, mission-control

When I activate mission control via F3 or a hot corner I have assigned the function to, I can choose which application to bring to the foreground. However, when I select Google Chrome and sometimes Finder, the selected application gets sent to the back, and some other application brought to the foreground. The only way to highlight the application I want is it use the Dock icon, click on the application window, or Command+Tab.

Sometimes I can get it to work with Finder if I use Terminal to do `killall Finder`

I've tried force quitting any applications/services/processes that I could think of that might affect Mission Control with no luck.

macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try updating to 10.12.5 first. They might have fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.